# Dynamic Date Filter

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm using Dynamic date filter by taking min and max from date table. The Dynamic title is working fine if I press date range in between Slicer.

Problem is, in my slicer I took relative date for 1 year for example: 01-nov 2019 to 31-oct-2020. if i filter any date in between the above dates my dynamic title is going to max of my date table not filter in between dates that I choose.

Example

if my date table have 01-oct-2000 to 01-Dec-2020 then I i choose a range in the slicer the dynamic title is going to max of the date that is "01-Dec-2020" but I need "31-oct-2020".

The current landing page displays 12month of dynamic title and slicer.
[image]

In the slicer If I press the date in between range the dynamic title is end date is going to Max of my date table but slicer end date value is different.
[image]

Comment: Show your measure code for start and end date.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Please see the dax measure below


measure = 

if(ISFILTERED('Date'[Date]),

"Start Date" & format(min(Date_ICSR[Date]),"dd-mmm-yyyy") &" and  End Date " & format(max(Date_ICSR[Date]),"dd-mmm-yyyy"),

"01-"& format((today()),"mmm")&"-"& year(TODAY())-1 & " and " & format(EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1),"dd-mmm-yyyy"))